# Error 400 when uploading an image to S3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, amazon-s3

I get the following error when I try to upload an image to S3:

```
POST https://bucket-name.s3.amazonaws.com/ 400 (Bad Request)
```

In my controller, I'm passing:

```
@s3_direct_post = S3_BUCKET.presigned_post(key: "uploads/#{SecureRandom.uuid}/${filename}", success_action_status: '201', acl: 'public-read')
```

In my view, I have:

```
<%= form_for(@student, html: { class: 'directUpload', data: { 'form-data' => (@s3_direct_post.fields), 'url' => @s3_direct_post.url, 'host' => URI.parse(@s3_direct_post.url).host } }) do |f| %>
```

initializers/aws.rb:

```
Aws.config.update({
  region: 'us-east-1',
  credentials: Aws::Credentials.new('ABC', 'XYZ'),
})

S3_BUCKET = Aws::S3::Resource.new.bucket('bucket-name')
```

I added the following CORS configuration to my bucket:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
<CORSRule>
    <AllowedOrigin>http://localhost:3000</AllowedOrigin>
    <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>POST</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>PUT</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
</CORSRule>
```

I followed the tutorial here: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/direct-to-s3-image-uploads-in-rails. Is there a difference between a "production bucket" and a "development bucket"?

Answer (score 0):

The issue was with the region. Interesting, because I thought S3 buckets are global.

Comment: You might want to review [Working with Amazon S3 Buckets](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingBucket.html).